# "I wish I went" or "I wish I had gone"

Tags: meaning, past-tense, past-perfect, wish

In the following sentences, there is probably an aspectual error.

Wouldn't that error rather be in:

> 'I wish I ***went*** to the party, which I had been invited to last week.'

than

> 'I wish I ***had gone*** to the party, which I had been invited to last
> week.'

?

**For me, "I wish I had gone..." absolutely fits in, making the order of events perfectly correct and suitable.**

Note: The only reason I have made this OP is because my professor, who is NOT a native English speaker, claims the opposite. He probably mistook subjunctive [mood] meaning for the literal meaning of the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are conditional sentences.
The first one is not correct. It’s the second conditional sentence kind,  which means that the use of ‘wish’ and a simple past verb expresses a desire that could come true in the future.

The second sentence is the third conditional sentence kind, it’s constructed using ‘wish’+ ‘had’/‘had not’ + past participle verb, and expresses regrets or past wishes.

It’s common for people to use them the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

For describes [wishes about the past](https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/wish) we usually use *past perfect* tense:

```
I wish I had brought my wallet.
```

And, when we need to talk about two past situations mutually related and clarify their chronology, we should use *present perfect + past perfect*:

```
They had called before it has happened.
```

**However**, your sentence don't actually treat about witch situation occurred first (although by context we are able to identify it). This way, the *simple past* is more natural and appropriate for the second phrase. Resulting at:

```
I wish I had gone to the party, which I was invited to last week.
```

The same way, there's no problem for use *past perfect* in the second sentence as well. Thus, your first alternative is not correct, but the following one is right.

```
I wish I had gone to the party, which I had been invited to last week.
```